# How to change/set template parameter based on type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization, class-template

I want to create a static class, which will act as fixed size memory allocator.

Lets look at this simplified example:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

template<class T, std::size_t MaxNumObjects>
class InternalContainer
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t maxObjects = MaxNumObjects;

    static T* createObject()
    {
        return ::new(&objects[idx++]) T;
    }
    static T* releaseObject() { /*...*/ };

private:
    using buffer_t = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;
    static buffer_t objects[maxObjects];
    static std::size_t idx;
};

A* a = InternalContainer<A, 2>::createObject();
B* b = InternalContainer<B, 5>::createObject();
```

**How can I predefine the maximum size of the container based on type?**

```
// will be replaced "InternalContainer<A, 2>"
A* a = MyContainer<A>::createObject(); 

// will be replaced "InternalContainer<B, 5>"
B* b = MyContainer<B>::createObject();
```

I have tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
template<class T>
using MyContainer = InternalContainer<A, 2>;
template<class T>
using MyContainer = InternalContainer<B, 5>;
```

Comment: Did you try defining a simple template something like `default_size<T>` that resolves to either 2 or 5? This can be done with textbook specialization. Then, just use that template in your `InternalContainer`. Mission accomplished.

Comment: How about some kind of *specialization*? Perhaps together with a generic base-class inherited with [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes the job any easier, but why is `MaxNumObjects` a template parameter at all?  Why not make it a parameter to the constructor?

Comment: To expand on the comment by @PaulSanders, what is your *actual*, *underlying* and *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you need a "container"? Why do you need to make it yourself? Why can't you use `std::array`? Right now this is really too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you ask about the actual, underlying and real problem (your *assignment*) then perhaps there might be other solutions, perhaps even better and simpler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by explicitly specializing a variable template, e.g.:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/zMz5MPxbP)

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

// default size for all InternalContainers
template<class T>
constexpr std::size_t InternalContainerDefaultSize = 64;
// specialization for A
template<>
constexpr std::size_t InternalContainerDefaultSize<A> = 2;
// specialization for B
template<>
constexpr std::size_t InternalContainerDefaultSize<B> = 5;

template<class T, std::size_t MaxNumObjects = InternalContainerDefaultSize<T>>
class InternalContainer {
    /* ... */
};


InternalContainer<A> aContainer; // size will be 2
InternalContainer<B> bContainer; // size will be 5
InternalContainer<C> cContainer; // size will be 64

// default size can be overriden by explicitly specifying another size
InternalContainer<A, 10> aContainer; // size will be 10
```

Comment: this is basically, what @Sam Varshavchik suggested and looks like most simple and clean solution, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

> How can I predefine the maximum size of the container based on type?

You have several options here.
The easiest, would be providing a specialization for the default types (i.e. `A`, `B` )

```
template <class T> struct MyContainer;
// specialization for A
template <> struct MyContainer<A> {
    using type = InternalContainer<A, 2>;
};
// specialization for B
template <> struct MyContainer<B> {
    using type = InternalContainer<B, 5>;
};
// ... so on!

// Helper alias
template <class T>
using MyContainer_t = typename MyContainer<T>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyContainer_t<A>, InternalContainer<A, 2>>);
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6n51jcKhM)

---

Alternatively, using [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (requires [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or higher) you might be able to do something like as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
constexpr auto typeHelper()
{
    // following requires the InternalContainer<T, N> be default constructible!!
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, A>) return InternalContainer<A, 2>{};
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, B>) return InternalContainer<B, 5>{};
}

template <class T>
using MyContainer = decltype(typeHelper<T>());

A* a = MyContainer<A>::createObject(); // will be replaced b InternalContainer<A, 2>
B* b = MyContainer<B>::createObject(); // will be replaced b InternalContainer<B, 5>
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vPj9ccTvf)

---

Alternatively, using [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) you could do also

```
#include <type_traits> //  std::conditional_t

template <class T>
using MyContainer = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, A>, InternalContainer<A, 2>,
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, B>, InternalContainer<B, 5>,
    /*Default case if types are not A nor B*/ void>
>;
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oKW6GKj7K)

Comment: Thanks for showing the different approaches to solve this issue

Comment: `if constexpr` solution sucks since code is not extensible. Basically `typeHelper` needs to know all types which should have custom size. In fact all solution here have this big disadvantage.

Comment: @MarekR Why is the if constexpr bad here? BTW, I see the solutions more or less showing OP, multiple alternatives, according to the requirements he/ she asked.

Comment: Problem is that your implementation depends on `A` and `B`. So if user of this code whish to customize number of items for other unknown class `X` he have to modify your code to add `if` for `X`. This is violation of open close principle. In other answer you can provide specialization and do not have to touch implementation detail.